# How to get a kubernetes pod to access an oracle database?

Tags: oracle, kubernetes, external, kubernetes-networkpolicy

I've been trying to get a kuberentes pod to access an external oracle databased. When the pod spins up, the PID associated to accessing the external oracle database hangs and does not timeout.

Here is my yaml:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: neuron-oracle-producer-clinrpt
  namespace: pubsub
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: neuron-oracle-producer-clinrpt
    spec:
      restartPolicy: Never
      hostNetwork: true
      containers:
      - name: neuron-oracle-producer-clinrpt
        image: ndtregistry.azurecr.io/neuron-oracle-producer-clinrpt:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        command: ["neuron-oracle-producer-clinrpt"]
        ports:
          - containerPort: 1521
            hostPort: 1521
        env:
        - name: ORA_USERNAME
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: clinrpt
              key: username
        - name: ORA_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: clinrpt
              key: password
        - name: QUEUE_HOST
          value: "broker.kafka.svc.cluster.local"
        - name: QUEUE_PORT
          value: "9092"
        - name: QUEUE_CATEGORIES
          value: "json"
        - name: LOG_FILE
          value: "/var/log/neuron-oracle-producer-clinrpt.txt"
        - name: MESSAGE_SOURCE
          value: "ClinRpt"
        - name: MESSAGE_FORMAT
          value: "json"
        - name: DEBUG
          value: "TRUE"
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 500m
            memory: 1Gi
          limits:
            cpu: 500m
            memory: 1Gi
        volumeMounts:
        - name: logs
          mountPath: /var/log/producer
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: azureregistry
      volumes:
      - name: logs
        emptyDir: {}
```

How do I get my pod to access an external oracle database?

Comment: Your manifest does not include details of the DB connection. It seems that your container is not able to access the remote database and is blocking as a result. Where is the connection defined? Can you ping the DB or access it from another machine? You may wish to inspect your container's logs (`kubectl logs pod/[pod-name] neuron-oracle-producer-clinrpt`). You may (depending on the image) be able to shell into your Pod and run the database client commands manually (`kubectl exec [pod-name]  --container=neuron-oracle-producer-clinrpt --stdin --tty -- /bin/bash`).

Comment: Exposing your container on the Pod's port 1521 is probably redundant. I think you intend for your Pod to access the DB on port 1521. This should work without needing to specify it.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The TNS string is defined in the docker build file as an environment variable. I've read some of the documentation for ingress, loadbalancer, and headless. I was not able to ascertain a direct route to define it. I experimented with each one and wasn't successful. How do you recommend defining the DB connection? Is there something extra I need to define in Kubernetes?

Comment: Ingress and Load-Balancers are to manage traffic incoming/ingressing to your cluster. IIUC you want your Pod to make outbound/egress calls and this should (!) just work. One approach you may take with debugging is to run a debugging container on the cluster from which you can test commands, e.g. `kubectl run debug --image=alpine --stdin --tty` and then you can, for example, `ping www.google.com` or `apk add curl && curl www.google.com`. Replace Google with your DB if it supports ping. Replace `alpine` with an Oracle DB client image to test that etc.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably too late, but you may want to try to add:

1. a k8s service to let the pod know there is a DB to call
2. a k8s endpoint to map the external IP address to the service

Rationale: by default K8s searches for local services. This creates a local service with a mapping to an external service's URI. More info: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/kubernetes-best-practices-mapping-external-services